# Is it possible to emit a warning on implicit float to bool conversion in MSVC?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, compiler-warnings

In this example I want MSVC to emit a warning:

```
auto func(float f) -> int {
  if(f) { return 654321;} // true if f != 0.0F
  else { return 123456; }
}
```

So that I'm forced to write:

```
auto func(float f) -> int {
  if(f != 0) { return 654321;}
  else { return 123456; }
}
```

Is it possible to make MSVC emit a warning on the implicit conversion in the first example?

Answer (score 1):

No, there is no such warning option in MSVC. You can verify this by compiling your example with `/Wall`, [which enables all warnings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/compiler-option-warning-level?view=msvc-160#remarks), and see that no warning is emitted.

There is, however, one such warning option in Clang: [`-Wfloat-conversion`](https://clang.llvm.org/docs/DiagnosticsReference.html#wfloat-conversion). The documentation says float to integer, but [it includes bool](https://godbolt.org/z/b6G6v9jeK).